# automatic resize of the tab panel based on contents

Tags: gwt

Hello I have implemented something like

```
private VerticalPanel resultPanel;
private TabLayoutPanel tabPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(2.5, Unit.EM);
ResizeLayoutPanel resizePanel = new ResizeLayoutPanel();

myMethod(){
    resizePanel.setWidth("100%");
    resizePanel.setHeight("415px");
    resizePanel.setWidget(tabPanel);

    resultPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    resultPanel.setWidth("100%");
        resultPanel.add(resizePanel);



        tabPanel.add(myVerticalPanel, tabHeader);
}
```

so the myVerticalPanel is the actual contents which is little large in height. As resizePanel height is set to 415px so rest of the contents are hidden.

I am looking for two things to achieve:
1. If there is a larger screen available then increase the tabPanel area to show more contents automatically
2. If screen is small then a scroll to appear to see rest of the contents

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace the `TabLayoutPanel` with a [HeaderPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HeaderPanel.html):

> A panel that includes a header (top), footer (bottom), and content
>   (middle) area. The header and footer areas resize naturally. The
>   content area is allocated all of the remaining space between the
>   header and footer area.

Alternatively you can override the `onResize()` method your `ResizeLayoutPanel` calculate the height of your embedded content and set the appropriate height.

If you want scrolling functionality you have to embed your `VerticalPanel` in a [ScrollPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html) or use CSS to set the oferflow property.